# Deep linking into an already open screen with different params. Is it possible?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I'm working on an app which has a category screen where the relevant posts of the category are displayed. I'm using react-navigation to navigate between the screens and handle the deep linking. The category screen can be accessed in-app or via deep link. To access the category screen via deep link I'm using something like `myapp://category/:id`.

If the app is already opened and is focused on the category screen the deep link does nothing.

I've currently "fixed" it using the `componentDidUpdate` life cycle method to compare the ID stored in the state and the ID in `navigation.getParam`.

```js
componentDidUpdate = () => {
  const { navigation } = this.props;
  const { categoryID } = this.state;
  const paramID = navigation.getParam('id', null);

  if (paramID !== categoryID) {
    this.setState({ categoryID: paramID }, () => {
      // fetch data
    });
  }
}
```

However, this seems like a dirty fix to me. Is there a better way of doing this? Maybe opening all deep links using push instead of navigate via react-navigation?

Comment: Why do you link the same screen again?

Comment: @hongdevelop I don't. That's the default behavior of the react-navigation library

Comment: @hongdeveloper that's nature. user seeing one screen, then open web to search another , deeplink link to same screen with different params.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who got here wondering how this can be done, like myself, here's the solution:

You can use the [`getId` `Stack.Screen` property](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen/#getid). You just need to return the unique ID from the `getId` property. Here's an example:

Let's say we have a `UserScreen` component, which is part of our `Stack` navigator. The `UserScreen` has one route param: `userId`. We can use the `getId` property like this:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AppStack = () => {
  const getUserRouteId = ({ params }) => {
    return params && params.userId;
  };

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      {/* Other routes */}
      <Stack.Screen name="User" component={UserScreen} getId={getUserRouteId} />
    </Stack.Navigator>;
  );
};
```

Now when you try to normally navigate to this route, using the `navigate` function, if the param `userId` in the navigation action is different than on the `UserScreen` which you're currently on, it will navigate you to a new user screen. [React Navigation deep linking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/) uses the `navigate` function internally.

Comment: confirming this works! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I employ this method: it takes the array and converts it in a specific manner to yield a distinct identifier for the parameters. Without this process, the functionality wouldn't be correct:

```
  function generateUniqueID(json) {
    const combinedString = Object.keys(json).sort().map(key => `${key}:${json[key]}`).join(';');
    
    let hash = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < combinedString.length; i++) {
      const char = combinedString.charCodeAt(i);
      hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + char;
      hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
    }
    
    return hash.toString();
  }
  const getUserRouteId = ({ params }) => {
    //console.log(generateUniqueID(params));
    return generateUniqueID(params);
  };
```